# How do I replace an array element in Java?

Tags: java

I have this array:

```
array = [null, p, ;, z,null, OR, y]
```

I want to replace null value by any other value. How do I do that?

Comment: You ran your question through some obscure obfuscator?

Comment: Kindly make the question clear. Are u asking something like how to replace a particular value with other or how to remove null values in a string array?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (pos=0;pos<array.length;pos++) {
    if(array[pos]==null) {
       array[pos]=xyz
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
String[] values= {null,"p", ";","z",null, "OR","y"};        
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
Collections.replaceAll(list, null, "newVal");
values = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```